App Gateway Rewrite set not adding custom request header
I've created an App Gateway with MTLS listener with app service as the backend pool. Added the client CA certs to the ssl profile.
I'm seeing mtls result as success in the logs, and also seeing the mtls listener getting resolved. With serverstatus = 403.
Rewrite set has been attached to the MTLS listener.
Rewrite set is adding custom request header e.g. X-ARR-Dummy-Header with value {var_client_certificate}.
App needs to use cert in the custom header to perform authorization.
I'm not seeing this new custom header reaching app service.
How to debug this issue?

AFAIK, you have to check the header using App Service logs only. Can you let me know how you are saying the header was not sent to App Service

I was logging header in the application logs.

The issue was that AppService was returning BadRequest. The request didn't even reach the application code.
AppService "Client certificate mode" was set to Require, which resulted in BadRequest from AppService. I updated it to Allow and I started to see requests reaching the application code, and the custom rewrite header became available for use by application.

Good to know your issue got resolved
